# how to catch the original data(x,y motion) from an optical mouse?

Tags: position, driver, mouse, motion

how to catch the original data(x,y motion) from an optical mouse
I work on ubuntu and centos,by some project I have to get the optical mouse data(x,y),not the position(x,y)on screen.
I need some help.Thanks!

Comment: there are 2 func in linux kernel driver/input/mousedev.c: ABS_X   ABS_Y , may it be help ?

Comment: Please post the code you have already tried, and an explanation of how it is not working.

Comment: I havn't code. I just insert some "printk" in driver/input/mousedev.c in order  to print the data(x,y)to dmesg,but it couldn't print anything.

Comment: an optical mouse will compute a motion data(x,y,z) by diff 2 pictures, I want to get this motion data(x,y),I don't need data(z).